# WSO2 EI 6.5.0 Sizing and Storate, Clustered Deployment

Tags: wso2, wso2-data-services-server, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-esb

I'm wondering how to *calculate storage usage or sizing* (**database, log files**, i do not know others) of WSO2 EI Clustered deployment (*Load balancer + Node 1 + Node 2* )

Wondering which hardware environment should we set up?
Our traffic is very high, almost receives 10000 request per day,

**1. Should we use hardware environment what WSO2 recommended ?**

Answer (score -1):

you can follow the production deployment guide[1] to follow the hardware requirements recommended by wso2. Basically follow the installation prerequisites[2] and common guidelines[3] sections on that doc.  Also for best practices for managing the logs can be found on [4]

[1] - https://docs.wso2.com/display/CLUSTER44x/Production+Deployment+Guidelines

[2] - https://docs.wso2.com/display/CLUSTER44x/Production+Deployment+Guidelines#ProductionDeploymentGuidelines-Installationprerequisites

[3] - https://docs.wso2.com/display/CLUSTER44x/Production+Deployment+Guidelines#ProductionDeploymentGuidelines-Commonguidelinesandchecklist

[4] - https://docs.wso2.com/display/ADMIN44x/Monitoring+Logs#MonitoringLogs-Managingloggrowth

Comment: Please try to write an actual answer and only use the links for reference. Right now your answer contains no solution to the question, only links to a possible solution.